# Flutter background service does not work ios

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, background-service

**flutter_background_service**

Although I wrote the same code in the example, the background service does not work on IOS. Also it works in android. Anybody have an idea?

I want to listen message from socket by use background-service but does not work background. If app closes, device disconnect socket.

library: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service/example

#### swift

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import flutter_background_service
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    static func registerPlugins(with registry: FlutterPluginRegistry) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
    }
    lazy var flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "MyApp")
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    flutterEngine.run()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self.flutterEngine)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
```

#### initialize in dart

```dart
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterBackgroundService.initialize(onStart);
  runApp(App());
}

void onStart() {
  // native service
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Get.put(SocketService());
}
```

##### socket service class

```dart
oid listenBackground() {
    service.onDataReceived.listen((event) {
      if (event!["action"] == "connect") {
        connectSocket(event['user'], event['token']);
        return;
      } else if (event['action'] == 'private message') {
        sendMessage(event['message']);
        return;
      } else if (event['action'] == 'typing') {
        setTyping(event['from'], event['to'], event['status']);
      } else if (event['action'] == 'send received message') {
        sendReceiveMessage(event['message']);
      } else if (event['action'] == 'set profile photo') {
        sendProfilePhoto(event['image'], event['id']);
      } else if (event['action'] == 'disconnect socket') {
        disConnect();
      } else if (event['action'] == 'connect socket') {
        connectSocketOnline();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: There is no way an app on ios can listen on a socket when it isn't the foreground app unless it is also performing some supported background task; The example for that package shows playing audio as an example

Comment: Thank you but it must work if does not  only option is firebase, i do not use it. Also if firebase can work bakcground some example whatsapp,Telegram etc. how can they work background.

Comment: They receive push notifications. This is very different to listening on a socket. The operating system handles that for them. VoIP apps that are in a call are also a permitted background mode, so they can keep a socket open while they are in a call.

Comment: Thank you! But I will try until tomorrow. If I succeed, i will let you know.

Comment: bro did you succeed?

Comment: No I didn't, background service doesn't work as i want.